# How to open .PRI files with Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourcesManager.LoadPriFiles?

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I want to open a generated .PRI file **(c:\test\resource.pri)** programatically using C#.

The problem is that the method for **ResourceManager** takes as argument an object of type **IEnumerable<IStorageFile>**

I would like to be able to do something like

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core;


ResourceManager rm = ResourceManager.Current;

//Now something like
IStorageFile stFile = IStorageFile.OpenPath(@"c:\test\resource.pri");
//but IStorageFile is static, how can I serialize it ??

IEnumerable<IStorageFile> files = new IEnumerable<IStorageFile>();
files.Add(stFile);

var priResources = rm.LoadPriFiles(files);

void process(priResources){
    //extract the resources from priResources
    //need this implementation also
}
```